# Java beginner in need of direction (I need to build an MP3 player in Java)

Tags: mp3, actionlistener

I'm taking a Java 101 class, and the teacher did as best she could to teach us all the material in such a short amount of time. Final projects are due, and I've been working on a Java MP3 Player  with my partner. When I say Java MP3 Player, imagine a proprietary touch-screen MP3 player on your computer monitor. That's sorta what I was trying to create. Just a basic array of buttons (Artists, Genres, Songs, etc). Complete with volume control buttons, and the ability to pause a song. (Imagine I'd have to somehow integrate Windows Media Player).

Man oh man, did I get stuck. I figured out how to actually play a song in Java, but not using WMP like I will ultimately need. I also made a jpg in Photoshop and made it my player background, and threw 5 JButtons on the screen.

I am having an AWFUL time figuring out how to make the interactive menu work. I have a TON of programming experience in HTML, CSS, and JASS (Warcraft 3 proprietary language), so I am no novice when it comes to the logistics. As of now, I've made it so the text on the button changes when you press it (simulating a menu change), but I can't get the other button text to change (as they're in a different class, and cannot be addressed). I don't have my code with me on this PC so I can't show you exactly where I am stuck..

Basically, I need to know the best approach to tackling this project. Do I have it all wrong with the 5 buttons, and manually creating the interactive menu using ActionListeners? (IF text on button = "Artists", then change button1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to *5 different artists*). Is this a bad approach? I couldn't seem to find any tutorials on this. I appreciate ANY AND ALL HELP!

If it's out of my league, I will happily choose another project. Thanks guys!

Comment: Isn't that a bit of an odd project for a "101" course? I thought those were mostly supposed to teach you how the language works, not go into full-blown GUI apps... (Also FYI, HTML and CSS are not programming).

Comment: Right, they aren't programming but I just wanted to confirm that I'm not new to "coding" in general. I know Visual Basic too. And yes, this class was NOT a walk in the park. The teacher kinda blew through things, and the GUI apps are a real thorn in my side. 

Don't get me wrong, this doesn't need to be fancy. Just basic buttons and functionality. Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 3):

The way you would like to update the text on the buttons and stuff is with something called the Observer pattern.

Basically you have some sort of a model that holds all the data of which song is being played, which artist it is, etc. When the data changes (example: song being played) the data tells all observers (your GUI) that something is updated, then you can simply pull all the data with getters form the model to the GUI. Example pseudo-code:

```
// this is our model
public class Mp3Player extends Observable {
    private MP3 songBeingPlayed;
    ...

    public setMp3(MP3 song){
        songBeingPlayed = song;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void nextSong(){
        // Todo: Change song
        ...

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();  // Notify GUI that something changed
    }
}

// this is our gui
public class GUI implements Observer {
    private Mp3Player player;
    private JLabel artistName;

    public GUI(){
         player = new Mp3Player();
         player.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object o1){
         // This method gets called when the model calls notifyObservers()
         artistName.setText(player.getArtistName());
         ...
    }

}

// Button implementation
public class NextSongButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    private Mp3Player player;

    public NextSongButton(Mp3Player player){
        this.player = player;
        ...

        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        player.nextSong();
    }

}
```

That was just a short example on how one could keep the GUI updated when the model changes. Instead of having all the logic in the buttons listeners.

Comment: I also added example implementation of a button to show you that there is no need for complex logic in the actionPerformed-methods, simply tell the model what you want to do (example: change song).